# PhantomJS : WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(Invalid)

Tags: phantomjs

I have a problem :

2017-02-18T20:19:16 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n        var ev = document.createEvent(\"MouseEvents\");\n        ev.initEvent(\"click\", true, true);\n\n        document.querySelector(\"#jeje\").dispatchEvent(ev);\n    })(); })()"

2017-02-18T20:19:16 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10

**2017-02-18T20:19:16 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(Invalid)**

Code JS :

```
page.open(address, settings, function(status) {

   // Check for page load success
   page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

      if (status !== "success") {
         console.log("==================Unable to access network==================");
      } else {
         // Wait for element to be visible
         waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible

            return page.evaluate(function() {

               return $("body").is(":visible");

            });

         }, function() {
            console.log("==================The element should be visible now.==================");


 page.evaluate(function() {
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        ev.initEvent("click", true, true);

        document.querySelector("#jeje").dispatchEvent(ev);
    })       

            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
         });
      }
   })
});
```

I do not understand the problem. Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome, you should explain what you are trying to achieve here. If you are having problems understanding the problem and you know what you are trying to do imagine the rest of us that have no idea of what should be the correct outcome :-)

Comment: Hello xperera,
I want PhantomJs to click on the ID #jeje"on the url target

<a href="url" id="jeje"><img src="test.jpg"></a>

Comment: How is that log line a problem?

Comment: Please @MickaelLeLoeuff elaborate a bit more on the expected outcome and include it in the question body, so that people can find all the details.